# NSInvalidArgumentException using AFNetworking to send audio to server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, multipartform-data

I am trying to send an audio file to my server using AFNetworking but so far without success. This is the code on my device:

```
self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[self.manager POST:@"upload.php"
    parameters:@{}
    constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:self.output.soundData name:@"audio" fileName:@"recordedSound.m4a" mimeType:@"audio/m4a"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

This is my code on the server:

```
<?php

define("WWW_ROOT",dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $target_path = WWW_ROOT ."uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['audio']['name']); 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
}
```

Whenever I try to send the data to the server, I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -streamStatus only defined for abstract class.  Define -[AFMultipartBodyStream streamStatus]!'

Comment: Really read the error message, it even tells you what to do: `Define -[AFMultipartBodyStream streamStatus]`

Answer (score 2):

same here just update AFNetworking to latest version and everything should work smooth.